# Parsing XML array using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, jquery-mobile

I have stuck up with an issue of passing XML using Jquery. I am getting empty array while traversing to jquery.Please help me how to get datas from XML array. I have mentioned my code below.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<json>
   <json>
     <CustomerName>999GIZA MID INSURANCEAND SERVICES PVT LTD</CustomerName>
      <mobiLastReceiptDate>null</mobiLastReceiptDate>
   </json>
   <json>

      <CustomerName>A  SHRIVENGATESH</CustomerName>
      <mobiLastReceiptDate>null</mobiLastReceiptDate>
   </json>
   <json>
      <CustomerName>A 1 PROCESS</CustomerName>
      <mobiLastReceiptDate>null</mobiLastReceiptDate>
   </json>
   <json>
      <CustomerName>A A A ENTERPRISES</CustomerName>
      <mobiLastReceiptDate>null</mobiLastReceiptDate>
   </json>
   <json>

      <CustomerName>A ALAGUSUNDARAM</CustomerName>
      <mobiLastReceiptDate>null</mobiLastReceiptDate>
   </json>
</json>
```

**Jquery**

```
page_response=getResponse("yyyURL");

page_response.success(function(data){
console.log(data.results[0]);
console.log($( data ).find( "CustomerName" ));

$(data).find("json").each(function(i, item) {
var heures = $(item).attr("CustomerName");
var nbr = $(item).attr("EMI");

<!--- Am getting array.. ineed to get name and EMI-->
console.log(heures);
});

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`EMI` and `CustomerName` are elements under `json` so you can use [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find) to find those elements and then [text()](https://api.jquery.com/text) to get its value.

```
$(data).find("json").each(function (i, item) {
    var heures = $(item).find("CustomerName").text();
    var nbr = $(item).find("EMI").text();
    console.log(heures);
});
```

[.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr) is used to get the attribute value of an element like in `<json EMI="abc">...</json>`

Answer (score 0):

You have used the wrong method for getting the node, basics of xml elements  is "node has attributes". So if you want to find any node in XML elements you can use jquery.find(), but when you want to find any attribute of some node in that case you can use jquery.attr() function.

Moreover, jquery.val() and jQuery.text() are the functions which are used for getting the values and the text of the elements respectively.

Hope this will help!!

Cheers!!